# How to return Values from each iteration of a for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script

THIS SCRIPT IS INTENDED TO ITERATE DOWN A LIST OF SPREADSHEET DATA AND SEND A HTML FORMATTED EMAIL WITH THAT DATA TO MY EMAIL ADDRESS. CODE.GS IS TO PASS THE VARIABLES TO INDEX.HTML SO THEY CAN BE FORMATTED NICELY AND SENT AS A HTML TEMPLATE. DATE: 09/09/2015 JFKAESE @ GMAIL . COM

**CODE.GS**

```
// THIS FUNCTION TAKES THE ITERATOR VARIABLE TO GO DOWN SHEET DATA
function emailBody(i){

  //GET SPREADSHEET BY ID AND SHEET NAME
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Wc0j3twn1i-ug-lCsWOxyk-8u9t21Vr_xJH9wVu4KTk');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  // GET DATA AND RETURN IT FOR THE HTML BODY
  var item1 = sheet.getRange(i,1).getValue();
  var item2 = sheet.getRange(i,2).getValue();
  return [item1, item2];

} 

// THIS FUNCTION LOOPS < 5 FOR TESTING PURPOSES BUT SHOULD GO
// UNTIL THE LAST ROW OF DATA

function looper() {
  for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++){

    // LOG THE OUTCOME -- WORKING PERFECT.
    // I NEED TO SEND THE DATA TO THE INDEX.HTML FOR FORMATTING
    Logger.log(emailBody(i));
  }
}

// THIS FUNCTION IS TO SEND THE EMAILS TO MY EMAIL ADDRESS
function sendEmails() {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');
  var body = template.evaluate().getContent();

  // SEND THE EMAIL
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    subject:"Test Email",
    to:"example@domain.com",
    htmlBody: body,
  });
}
```

**INDEX.HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <body style="background-color:#F5F5F5">


    <p><? var data = emailBody(); ?></p>
    <p><? var item1 = data[0]; ?></p>
    <p><? var item2 = data[1]; ?></p>
    <p><?= item1 ?>
    <p><?= item2 ?>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you check the answer???

Comment: @psylogic ive posted my code. hopefully you can make sense of it .

Comment: @psylogic the idea is to send one html formatted email per line of spreadsheet data

Answer (score 1):

Change the function definition a little bit and call it inside a loop. And this is how you'll have two values returned for every iteration.

```
 function emailBody(i){
          var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('A_SHEET_ID_HERE');
          var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');


            var item1 = sheet.getRange(i,1).getValue();
            var item2 = sheet.getRange(i,2).getValue();
            return [item1, item2];


        } 
 for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++){
    console.log( emailBody(i));
    }
```

For passing the value you can do it like this, how do you want to get the values is upto you:

**HTML**

```
<p id="item1"></p>
<p id="item2"></p>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
document.getElementById("item1").innerHTML=item1;
document.getElementById("item2").innerHTML=item2;
```

Comment: This code is great and it does exactly want you say it does. My problem now is that I cannot figure out how to pass the returned values to my .html file.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I can't work it out. I might be a little over my head with this one. ill work on it and post if i can make it happen. Thanks again!

Comment: you can tell me exactly what you want to do and i'll tell you how to do it!

Answer (score 0):

Store the items you want returned into a variable so that the for loop can finish executing and then execute the return statement with variable being passed at the end of the for loop?